# Use Ruby, Cucumber and Aruba to check for file in testing home directory

Tags: ruby, cucumber, aruba

I'm using Cucumber and Aruba to test a Ruby command line app written on top of [GLI](https://github.com/davetron5000/gli). To prevent tests from affecting production data, I update `ENV['HOME']` to point to a testing directory. I'd like to check for the existence of a file in the testing `ENV['HOME']` directory. I'd like to use Aruba for this, but I have been unable to get `ENV['HOME']` to expand properly.

For example:

```
Scenario: Testing config files are found
  Given I switch ENV['HOME'] to be "set_a" of test_arena
  Then a file named "#{ENV['HOME']}/config.xml" should exist
```

Is it possible to pass ENV['HOME'] to Aruba's `Then a file named "" should exist` step_definition and have it expand to the full path?

Answer (score 2):

I'm still interested in seeing if it's possible to do this natively with Cucumber/Aruba. In the mean time, here's a cut down example of what I'm doing:

In `features/app_name.feature` file, define the following Scenario:

```
Scenario: Testing config files are found
  Given I switch ENV['HOME'] to be "test_arenas/set_a"
  Then a test_arena file named "config.xml" should exist
```

Then, in the `features/step_definitions/app_name.rb` file define the steps:

```
Given(/^I switch ENV\['HOME'\] to be "(.*?)"$/) do |testing_dir|
  ENV['HOME'] = File.join(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)), 
    '..','..', testing_dir)
end

Then(/^a test_arena file named "(.*?)" should exist$/) do |file_name|
  file_path = "#{ENV['HOME']}/#{file_name}"
  expect(File.exists?(file_path)).to be_truthy
end
```

This isn't as robust at Aruba's [`check_file_presence`](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba/blob/7afbc5c0cbae9c9a946d70c4c2735ccb86e00f08/lib/aruba/api.rb#L106) but it gets the basic job done.

---

*For a little more background, the idea behind this approach is to have a `test_arenas` directory sitting at the root of the app's directory structure. For each test, an individual `test_arenas/set_X` directory is created that contains the necessary files. Prior to each test, ENV['HOME'] is pointed to the respective `test_arenas/set_X` directory.*